# React Navigation probem with StackNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

It's been two days that I'm stuck in this problem. I can't figure how to resolve this. I know the error is that I can't use `this.porps` there, but I don't know how to fix. I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

[image: This is the error:]

This is my Navigator config:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from './screens/auth/Login';
import CadastroScreen from './screens/auth/Cadastro';

class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LoginScreen />
    );
  }  
}

class Cadastro extends React.Component {
  render() 
    {
    return (
      <CadastroScreen />
    );
  }  
}

const AppNavigator = {
    Cadastro: {
      screen: Cadastro,
      navigationOptions: { header: null }
    },
    Login: {
      screen: Login,
      navigationOptions: { header: null }
    },
  };

const Config = {
    initialRouteName: 'Login'
}

const AppNavigation = createStackNavigator(AppNavigator, Config);
export default createAppContainer(AppNavigation);
```

This is how I'm trying to change screens:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button, Alert, TextInput, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
import Patern from '../style/Style';
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {      
        return (
            <View style={Patern.container}>                
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => 
                       this.props.navigation.dispatch(
                        StackActions.reset({
                          routeName: 'Cadastro',
                          index: 0,
                          actions: 
                          NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Cadastro' })
                 }))}>
                </TouchableOpacity>                
         </View>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Login extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <LoginScreen navigatoin={this.props.navigation} />
    );
  }  
}
```

You need to pass the props from `Login` to `LoginScreen`.
Navigation prop is only passed to one depth from `Navigator`.